# No compile time error when a return path exists without expected return type

Tags: java, c

I was wondering why does the following code not throw an error during compilation? :

```
#include <stdio.h>
char * func (char *);

int main()
{
    func("TINFO");
    func("INFO");
}

char * func(char * str)
{
    if (str[0] == 'T')
    return str + 1;
}
```

You see there is a return path from the function that does not return a `char *`

Similar Java code throws a compile time error, though.

Compiler used:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
```

Comment: post your Java translation to see the errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to C standard, 6.9.1.12, reaching an end of the function is undefined behavior *only if the caller uses the returned value*:

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

That's why the compiler must let this code compile.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is raise the "warning" level on your compiler.

EXAMPLE:

```
$ gcc -o x x.c
  <= DEFAULT: No warnings, no errors

$ gcc -Wall -pedantic -o x x.c
x.c: In function `main':
x.c:14: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
x.c: In function `func':
x.c:24: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Comment: But it is a warning and not an ERROR like what Java does ( for similar code).